# React Native Linking event listener not firing on Android

Tags: firebase, react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using React Native Firebase Dynamic Links to get the deep linking functionality.
I have added following intent-filter to AndroidManifest.xml file. But when I click on the link It open up the app but not firing the Linking event listener for Android. It works fine for iOS.

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:host="dev.page.link" android:scheme="http"/>
      <data android:host="dev.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>


//Listener added in component

 componentDidMount() {

    Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
      this.navigate(url);
    });

    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }
```

Comment: same problem... any solution?